# Message count won't clear for inbox

Tags: support

Starting yesterday, there's a "4" badge on my inbox that won't go away no matter how many times I view the already seen items.

New bug in code, or some sort of corruption in cookies?

The CAPTCHA failed on Safari, so I posted this on Firefox.  But the badge won't go away on Firefox either.  Which suggests that it isn’t cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a global change. As far as I can see, you can click on the letter icon at the right of each message to toggle "read" state (and change the counter as well). There is also a "Mark all [as] read" option on top.

More details can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live).

Comment: It's super-annoying to change an accustomed behaviour for no greater functionality.

Comment: @benwiggy There is a discussion on Meta.SE about bringing back the old functionality as a toggle. I actually kind of like the new behaviour, but it's also clear that not everybody needs a reminder to go back to old notifications :)